# Is it possible to find the radius of a cylinder, given only the volume and lateral area?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to find the radius of a cylinder, given only the volume and lateral area? If so, what formula would be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V = \pi r^2 h\\
A = 2\pi r h\\
\frac {V}{A} = \frac {\pi r^2 h}{2\pi r h} = \frac {r}{2}$

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality questions.